# How do you refresh a page and persist the Referer header

Tags: javascript, html, http-referer

I need to pragmatically refresh my page (for example `location.reload(true);`) but also maintain the original http referer header.

the http referer header persists if you click the refresh button on your browser.  I know there are a [ton](http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html) of different ways to refresh the page in javasript, is there a way to maintain the http referer?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manually set REFERER header in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580575/how-to-manually-set-referer-header-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

You can't force the value of the `document.referrer` to be something specific from a reload. But there are workarounds.

A quick, unobtrusive technique is to persist this state in the user's [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```
// Get the last known referrer
const referrer = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myApp')).referrer;

// Save the current referrer.
localStorage.setItem('myApp', JSON.stringify({
    referrer : document.referrer
}));
```

You could also tie some state to a reload by storing it in a query string or fragment identifier.

```
const referrer = document.referrer;

if (referrer) {

    let query = location.search;

    if (query) {
        query += '&';
    }

    query += 'referrer=' + encodeURIComponent(referrer);

    location.search = query;  // reloads the page
}
```

However, if you don't have much control over the page content, the query string approach can be problematic because some applications (front-end and back-end) that see a query will think they need to do something special. So it has a potential for unintended side effects.