# Can I change referer in jsp or how to change referer？

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, web-crawler, http-referer

1. What I wanted to do is set different referer for every Link：

[image: The Links]

2.The explanation below is my attempt：

Code 1:

```
<a class="mymovie"
    mytitle="<s:property value="movieLink"/>"
    title="<s:property value="movieDownloadPath"/>" 
    href="javascript:void(0)">
      <s:property value="movieName"/>
</a>
```

Code 2:

```
$(".mymovie").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type:"get",
      url:$(this).attr("title"),
      beforeSend: function(request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Referer", $(this).attr("mytitle"));
                },
   });
   alert($(this).attr("title"))
});
```

3. The effect

> chorm，jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4 Refused to set unsafe header "Referer"，jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load “This is a FTP link to download movie（like:ftp:/.....rmvb）” Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

[image: the effect in chorm]

In Firefox，when I click one link, there is no effect. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, changing the `referer` header is not allowed. [There seems to be a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24674913/227884), though:

```
delete window.document.referrer;
window.document.__defineGetter__('referrer', function () {
    return "yoururl.com";
});
```