# How to set referer in header in SmartTV app

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I develop a SmartTV app therefore it's not hosted on any domain.

The service my methods ping are checking the referer from which the request originated, and approve just some specific domains (including my website, e.g. https://example.com)

How do I "manipulate" request header referer value, in order to be recognized by the service?

Comment: You are going to need a lot more details about how your app is actually executed.  Is it in a web browser of some kind? In which case [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580575/how-to-manually-set-referer-header-in-javascript) may be of use, but otherwise you will need more details about how your application make the HTTP requests.

Comment: It is executed local in a web browser of SmartTV, so there is no domain. That thread didn't help me out in my case.

Comment: Well, that thread basically tells you that you can't set the referrer header when making a request from a web browser.  You will need to install some kind of helper that runs outside the web browser to make the request on your web browser application's behalf.