# How to set custom referrer value on redirect

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, http-headers

I am trying to setup a custom referrer value while redirecting. I am trying this with both Javascript and PHP but none of them are working.

**JS code :** `window.document.__defineGetter__`

```
<script>
var reff = ["https://www.stackoverflow.com", "https://www.stackexchange.com"];
var randomreff = reff[Math.floor(Math.random()*reff.length)];
delete window.document.referrer;
        window.document.__defineGetter__('referrer', function () {
            return randomreff;
        });
</script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  window.location.href = "https://www.example.com";
};
</script>
```

**JS Code :** `Object.defineProperty`

```
const reff = ["https://www.stackoverflow.com", "https://www.stackexchange.com"];
const randomreff = reff[Math.floor(Math.random()*reff.length)];
Object.defineProperty(document, "referrer", {get : function(){ return randomreff; }});
window.onload = function() {
  window.location.replace("https://www.example.com");
};
```

**PHP code :**

```
//header("Referrer-Policy: no-referrer");
header("Referer: http://www.stackoverflow.com");
header("Location: https://example.com", true, 301);
```

**Note :** I have already checked the article [How to manually set REFERER header in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580575/how-to-manually-set-referer-header-in-javascript) and ***this is not a duplicate***. Above article to set referrer on current window and i want to set custom referrer on redirected window/website.

Comment: _"and i want to set custom referrer on redirected window/website"_ - and what makes you think that _should_ be possible ...?

Comment: `header("Referer: http://www.stackoverflow.com");` - absolutely utterly pointless, of course - `Referer` is a _request_ header, `header()` in PHP sets _response_ headers.

Comment: @CBroe I have mixed review upon searching on Google. So, thought it might be possible as referrer value is not `read-only` because i am able to change on `my current page`. I hope there can be any way where i can send a custom referrer value.

Comment: `i am able to change on my current page`...maybe, but the browser will not allow it to be transmitted to another site. You can do what you want with your own page. This question is already answered.

Comment: `I have mixed review`...such as? Please provide links to sources which tell you that setting a custom referer is possible (and preferably actually demonstrate it).

Comment: @ADyson I got it. I thought because i am the open redirecting it to external domain maybe i can able to send some value. Like "No-referrer" rules works but custom referrer don't.

Comment: No, you can't do it because it's effectively providing dishonest information to the receiving site. You can maybe imagine how that could be horribly mis-used. REFERER can already by spoofed by non-browser HTTP clients (as can any request header or value, of course), but there is a safeguard built into standards-compliant browsers so it can't be exploited by dodgy websites etc. on behalf of end users.

Comment: JavaScript can intercept and manipulate background requests for the current site (https://stackoverflow.com/q/43813770/1427878), but I don't think the same thing is possible for "linking" to an external page.

Comment: @ADyson i understood totally. Custom referrer is not possible but how it can be harmful. Referrer are just value and it cannot harm external website or visitors.

Comment: It can if they rely on it for referral / usage statistics, advertising / afilliate revenue etc.